# Scrolling of clicked link in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Please see http://paramasivan.in/iframe/example/index2.html

I am using iframe-resizer script available at https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

When bottom image link is clicked it goes to bottom of that iframe. It is not scrolling to top.  I am using the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        iFrameResize({log : true,  checkOrigin : false, interval : 1000000,  warningTimeout : 1000000}, '#myIframe'); 
function resize(){
if ('parentIFrame' in window) {
// Fix race condition in FireFox with setTimeout
setTimeout(parentIFrame.size.bind(parentIFrame),0);
 }
}
var isOldIE = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") !== -1); // Detect IE10 and below

iFrameResize({
 heightCalculationMethod: isOldIE ? 'max' : 'lowestElement',
 minSize:100
}); 

//function readyCallback() {

  if ('parentIFrame' in window) {
  parentIFrame.scrollTo(0,0);
 }
// } 
</script>
```

Can you please give the code for scrolling to top ?

Any help ?

Comment: you can't access a cross domain iframe due to *"same origin policy"*

Comment: checkOrigin is given as false in the script and so cross domain iframe is possible.

Comment: ok...so you control the code inside that cross domain iframe? If so you need to implement scroll to top in code inside that page

Comment: Please see the documentation at https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer  They have given call back methods for scrolling to top.